# Why should I prefer using API async fucntions over wrapping synchronous ones with Task.Run?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library, threadpool

I know there is a difference between this code:

```
var streamWriter = new StreamWriter("something.txt");
streamWriter.WriteAsync("text");
```

and this:

```
var streamWriter = new StreamWriter("something.txt");
Task.Run(()=> streamWriter.Write("text"));
```

the first one makes much more sense.

and in different scenario when I am awaiting a result, this code:

```
var streamReader = new StreamReader("something.txt")
char[] chars = new char[10];

Task<int> task = streamReader.ReadAsync(chars, 0, chars.Length);
//Do something...

int num = await task;
//Do something with num...
```

makes much more sense than this:

```
var streamReader = new StreamReader("something.txt")
char[] chars = new char[10];

Task<int> task = Task.Run(()=>streamReader.Read(chars, 0, chars.Length));
//Do something...

int num = await task;
//Do something with num...
```

I guess the use of the built in async API is better not only in clarity and it actually manages the `ThreadPool` threads better and in more efficient way than having a `ThreadPool` thread waiting for no reason.

Is it right?

Comment: This is the typical pure async vs async over sync question.

Comment: The bet is that the people who implemented the `DoSomethingSomethingAsync` methods understood the problem domain and actually did a good job of implementing a good asynchronous story. The other way, spawning an explicit task to do a synchronous call pretty much says "I don't trust them". I think you should trust them.

Comment: In general, it *should always* be better to use asynchronous methods than to spawn a task and then call a synchronous method in that task, assuming you have the choice. Again, assuming whoever made the asynchronous methods knew what they were doing.

Comment: FYI, this exact subject is covered heavily in Tip 4 of [Lucian Wischik's "Six Essential Tips for Async" video series on Channel 9](https://aka.ms/ch9-async-tips).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A synchronous call wrapped in a `Task.Run` will block a thread pool thread for the duration of that operation. A truly asynchronous implementation [will not](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

With streams in particular, whether the operation is "truly asynchronous" can be a bit tricky to determine. For example, network streams are always truly asynchronous, memory streams are never truly asynchronous, and file streams are only truly asynchronous if you pass a special flag to their constructor.